# Сортировка по Id3tag

Tags: linux, terminal

Помогите написать скрипт, который бы сортировал музыку по id3Tag(у) на Линукс. То есть в зависимости от жанра совал музыку по соответствующим папкам.

Comment: В сообществе askubuntu.com как раз есть [ответ](http://askubuntu.com/a/9664/273483) на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky предлагаете перевести приведённую мной ссылку? Зачем?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Я вижу три основных причины. 1) Вопрос на AskUbuntu могут удалить, ссылка сломается. 2) Далеко не все участники русскоязычного сообщества владеют английским языком. 3) Ваша личная экспертиза по данному вопросу – бесценна.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо за ответ. Постараюсь перевести.

Comment: RenRot делает это и многое другое. http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/renrot/manual/html_chapter/Description.html. Don't worry about JPEG, basically it uses ExifTool perl library which also may handle id3tags, that are part of Exif in generic meaning.